# array definition not valid to Xlint

Tags: java, arrays

I am getting a compile error. "warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion"

> ArrayList[] regionTroops = new ArrayList[2];
>   
> required: ArrayList[]
>     found:    ArrayList[]

```
public class ContClass {
String name;
ArrayList<Integer>[] regionOwned = new ArrayList[2];
}
```

The code works, but I would like to eliminate the warning.
I set the value as follows.

```
ContData[n].regionOwned[0].add(rn);
```

Comment: *"I am getting a compile error"* No, you're getting a compiler *warning*, not an error.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a good IDE, it would help to add the annotation needed to suppress the warning.

Since you don't seem to be using such an IDE, here's the annotation you need:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
ArrayList<Integer>[] regionOwned = new ArrayList[2];
```

The warning is there to tell you that you're not going to get an array of `ArrayList<Integer>`, so the code will not be as type-safe as it's supposed to be.

See also: [How to create a generic array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/529085/5221149)